# Help Combine These Two PHP Codes

Tags: posts, php, post-formats

I have my WordPress post format codes:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_format( 'image' )) {
  echo 'This is a image post';
} ?>
```

And my code to grab the first image from a post...

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<?php $image = catch_that_image();
if( $image ) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image; ?>&amp;h=240&amp;w=280" class="index" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
</a>
```

So how do I put the image which is grabbed into the first code?

Thanks for all the help guys and gals, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_format( 'image' )) {
?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
   <?php $image = catch_that_image();
   if( $image ) { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image; ?>&amp;h=240&amp;w=280" class="index" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
   <?php } ?>
   </a>
<?php
} ?>
```